# What to do when a question marked as a duplicate is better than the original question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730) is marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297). But the first is actually a much better question. The second question has a title which is not descriptive, and no details about a HTTP 500 in the question body, so it doesn't show up in searches when people search for "what's causing my php 500 error".

In fact, I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008256) yesterday because I couldn't find an authoritative question when I searched, and only found the original question after it was marked as a duplicate by another user.

It seems like there should be some way of directing users toward a well-asked question with a good title. Would it make sense to heavily edit the original question? Can a duplicate flag ever be removed or reversed? Is there some better way to handle this?

Comment: well 113 thousand people managed to find it despite it's problems, so it can't be *that* bad...

Comment: i mean... which of the two titles will match what users who have no idea what their doing search for this problem? i'd say the older one.

Comment: I think most users, including those who have no idea what they're doing, who encounter this problem are searching for something like "php 500 internal server error", none of which are in the older question. "White screen of death" is not a thing that I'd expect people to look up.

Comment: That assumes they know an error is occurring.

Comment: In this particular case, they usually do. The questions tend to be along the line of "I'm getting a 500, here's my code, what's wrong". And the answers to those questions always tend to be that you need to find the logs to get a real exception/stack trace.

Comment: Because the 500 is the error they see in the client (the browser), not the error that's actually thrown by the server.

Comment: Fortunately we now have this new question as a sign post for users who know an error is occuring

Answer (score 6):

By far the easiest fix to a question not having a descriptive title is to *edit the title to make it more descriptive*.

Yes, it's possible to reverse the direction of the duplication, but that's not really needed just because you think the title could be a bit more descriptive.  That's more appropriate when the answer(s) on one are much better than the other, or there are really dramatic problems with the open question that aren't easily resolved by editing, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a duplicate flag ever be removed or reversed?

Yes. If you have a gold badge in a tag used in both questions, you can do it on your own by reopening one question and closing the other against it. The caveats in [Servy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366569/2751851) still apply: it is only worth bothering with that if there are significant differences between the Q&As that can't be dealt with through edits.